# Writing 1+1= 2 in a complicated way

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I am learning Unit Circle at the moment and I am using this source as an education tool [Trigonometry: Unit Circle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=593w799sBms) (Starts at 20:00).

The author solves these simple equations like below:

```
1 + 1 = 2
1 + 3 = 4
3 + 1 = 4
```

After he introduces this formula:

```
(√x)² = x
```

The first equation is then reintroduced to:

```
 (√1)² +  (√1)² =  (√2)²
 (√1)² +  (√3)² =  (√4)²
 (√3)² +  (√1)² =  (√4)²
```

I understand this, since the formula above says the square root of any number squared will equal the number.

The author then `divides` the `first two numbers x and y` by the `answer` and he is given the answer `1`.

[image: "Clean up the right hand side, take the answer and divide it by x and y"]

During some more "Clean up" as the author describes, this is the final out come;
[image: Final "Clean Up"]

I understand steps one and two, but when it comes to the third step, where he "cleans up" again, I get lost in thought. I would Google this, but I do not know the technical term, hence the title saying "Writing 1+1= 2 in a complicated way".

Can someone please give me the technical term, for this and simplify the learning curve. Or do I not need this understanding, in order to move on to the next stage where Pythagoras theorem is used to find generated points in a circle and so on.

Comment: I don't understand what he (or you) is trying to do here? All you are doing is re-expressing one set of expressions in an equivalent form using more symbols?

Comment: @Shaktal He is going to use the end results to plot points on a unit circle. For example, between 0 and 90 is 45. He will use these sets to plot them. for 45 he chooses the second set in the green box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the frames you've posted, it appears the video starts with an equation
$$
a + b = c
$$
involving *positive* numbers, and after some algebraic manipulation arrives at a point on the "unit circle":
$$
\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{c}}\right)^{2} + \left(\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{c}}\right)^{2} = 1.
$$
I don't know of a specific name for this, but in case it helps, here are the steps:
\begin{align*}
a + b &= c && \\
(\sqrt{a})^{2} + (\sqrt{b})^{2} &= (\sqrt{c})^{2} && \text{$x = (\sqrt{x})^{2}$ if $x \geq 0$;} \\
\frac{(\sqrt{a})^{2}}{(\sqrt{c})^{2}} + \frac{(\sqrt{a})^{2}}{(\sqrt{c})^{2}} &= 1 && \text{divide through by $(\sqrt{c})^{2}$;} \\
\left(\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{c}}\right)^{2} + \left(\frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{c}}\right)^{2} &= 1 && \frac{(\sqrt{a})^{2}}{(\sqrt{c})^{2}} = \left(\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{c}}\right)^{2}.
\end{align*}
Introducing
$$
x = \frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{c}},\quad
y = \frac{\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{c}},
$$
you have $x^{2} + y^{2} = 1$.

Comment: The letters make it very clear to understand, I must say. I understand it better now, but it will take some time for me to process it. I'm grateful for the answer.

Comment: @Moynzy: Glad to hear it was helpful. One pleasant feature of mathematics is that sometimes a more general argument is easier to understand than a special case. :)